# Hide image if its height is bigger than its width

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have **many pictures** in my page, and I want to hide those **whose height is greater than the width**.
I tried with this simple code, but it doesn't work.
HTML

```
<img src="/path/img_1" class="my_pictures_class">
<img src="/path/img_2" class="my_pictures_class">
<img src="/path/img_3" class="my_pictures_class">
<img src="/path/img_4" class="my_pictures_class">
<img src="/path/img_5" class="my_pictures_class">
...
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
   var i, img;
   var img = document.getElementsByClassName("my_pictures_class"); 
   for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
     var width = img.clientWidth;
     var height = img.clientHeight;
     if (height>width){
       img[i].style.display = "none";
     }
     else{
        //Nothing
     }
   }
};
```

I can't use Jquery. 
Thanks

Comment: check this again    `var width = img.clientWidth;
     var height = img.clientHeight;`

Comment: If your running the code Eugen sent and it is still not picking up on the height and width of the images. Can I ask if you have your script tag at the top (above the images) or at the bottom (below the images) in the HTML

Comment: It is at the bottom

Comment: Ok good, have you tried document.ready instead of onload? Only thing I can think is that the timing is off and the images are not getting loaded before the script runs.

Comment: The problem is that i can't use JQuery, but i can try to put my code at the top of the page

Comment: Right sorry forgot document.ready is jQuery.. apparently window.onload does wait for the content (including images) in some browsers. My only thought is that their height and width is not registering because they might not be all the way in there yet

Comment: You can test when the window.onload fires vs when your images load by using window.onload and img[i].onload and console.log the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are forgetting the indexes of the image array

```
window.onload = function() {
  var i, img;
  var img = document.getElementsByClassName("my_pictures_class");
  for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    var width = img[i].clientWidth;
    var height = img[i].clientHeight;
    if (height > width) {
      img[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
};
```

Consider forEach

```
const imgList = document.getElementsByClassName("my_pictures_class");
Array.from(imgList).forEach(img => {
  const height = img.clientHeight
  const width = img.clientWidth
  if (height > width) {
    img.style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

Comment: console.log your height and width to see if they even exist

Comment: Though my images are visible, the result of the console.log is 0

Comment: you should get them even though you haven't assigned attributes to them, is your image displaying?

Comment: Sure, they are displayed and visible. I just wrote this code...
`var width = img[i].clientWidth;
        var height = img[i].clientHeight;
        console.log(width);
        console.log(height);`

Answer (score 1):

You missed to mention the index. Though you can avoid using index by using `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()` like the following way:

```js
window.onload = function() {
   var imgList = document.querySelectorAll(".my_pictures_class");
   imgList.forEach(function(img){
     var width = img.clientWidth;
     var height = img.clientHeight;
     if (height>width){
       img.style.display = "none";
     }
     else{
        //Nothing
     }
   });
};
```

```html
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png" class="my_pictures_class">
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" class="my_pictures_class">
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png" class="my_pictures_class">
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/serrano.png" class="my_pictures_class">
<img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png" class="my_pictures_class">
```